# jsonmap in struts2 jquery grid

Tags: grid, struts2-jquery

What is "jsonmap" attribute in struts2 jquery gridcolumn tag?

Please tell me about jsonmap.

Is it used to develop grid dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Jsonmap Defines the json mapping for the column in the incoming json string
some more information can be found here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data